# Find the largest and smallest file with one loop in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the smallest and largest file in C with `stat()`. It's easy to initialize the counter `i` with `0` and then compare one by one but IDK how to initialize `j`. Hence the largest value can be found but not the smallest.

I know there is something wrong with the `j` part but I'm not sure how to initialize `j` to the first file and then get going. I feel there is other issues as well but IDK.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** So I added some lines as per David's suggestion but I seem to have some misunderstanding in stat used as buffer cause the both results show the largest value. Why does this happen?

**EDIT2:** Never mind I reentered the Linux environment it's fine now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    struct stat filestat;
    struct stat statbuf;
    struct stat statbuf1; //unsure if I should use another buffer for the min
    char *large_name;
    char *small_name;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;

    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Please enter ONE dir parameter\n");
        return 1;
    } else
    if (argc == 1) {
        dp = opendir("./");
    } else {
        dp = opendir(argv[1]);
    }
    if (dp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open dir.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        stat(dirp->d_name,&filestat);

        if (S_ISREG(filestat.st_mode)) {
            stat(dirp->d_name, &statbuf);
            //stat(dirp->d_name, &statbuf1);
            if (statbuf.st_size > max) {
                max = (statbuf.st_size);
                large_name = (dirp->d_name);
            }
            if (statbuf.st_size < min) {
                min = (statbuf.st_size);
                small_name = (dirp->d_name);
            }
        }
    }
    // Close directory and exit.

    printf("the largest file is %s\n", large_name);
    printf("the smallest file is %s\n", small_name);
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` and set `int j = INT_MAX;` (though you should rename `i` to `max` and `j` to `min` so they are actually meaningful names.) You can set `int i = INT_MIN;` as well (though for file sizes, `0` is fine) The key is to initialize your `min` to the max possible value and your `max` to the minimum possible value.

Comment: Hello David thanks .. but is there anything wrong with my stat buffer struct? Both result come out the same file/value.

Comment: All you need is `stat(dirp->d_name,&filestat);` You don't need the others. Once you have `st_size`, you have the file size. After `if(S_ISREG(filestat.st_mode)`, just compare `if(filestat.st_size > max) {...` You can shorten your intro to `dp = (argc < 2) ? opendir("./") : opendir(argv[1]);` You don't care if there are extra arguments given, they are ignored. Then just check your `if (dp==NULL){...` (or shorthand `if (!dp) {...`)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the storage needed for `large_name` and `small_name` of `PATH_MAX` characters to ensure the longest PATH and filename will fit, you need to form the complete relative filename before calling `stat()`. (`PATH_MAX` is `4096` on Linux and I believe `512` on windows) For example if you pass a directory to search to your program, calling `stat()` with `dirp->d_name` only provides the "name" not "../path/name" from the current location.

This can be done by storing the path to search (say in `srchdir[PATH_MAX]`) and then combining `srchdir` with a path separator (e.g. `'/'`) and `dirp->d_name` using `sprintf()`. You can simply define a `PATHSEP`, e.g.

```c
#define PATHSEP "/"       /* path component separator */
```

Then at the beginning of your code, fill `srchdir` with the path provided or `"."` by default, trimming any trailing `'/'` from the directory name provided, e.g.

```c
  if (argc > 1) {               /* set srchdir name (remove trailing '/') */
    size_t len;
    
    if (strlen (argv[1]) >= PATH_MAX) {  /* validate argv[1] <= PATH_MAX */
      fputs ("error: argument exceeds PATH_MAX characters.\n", stderr);
      return 1;
    }
    
    strcpy (srchdir, argv[1]);        /* copy argv[1] to srchdir */
    len = strlen (srchdir);           /* get length */
    /* if not '/' alone and if '/' found and at last char in string */
    if (srchdir[len-1] == '/')
      len--;                          /* len excludes the trailing '/' */
  } else {
    strcpy (srchdir, ".");            /* otherwise, use '.' */
    len = 1;
  }
  dp = opendir (srchdir);       /* opendir */
```

Now to combine `srchdir` with `PATHSEP` and `dirp->d_name`, you can simply use `sprintf()` (or `snprintf()` as recommended to ensure a component cannot be crafted to overflow `fname`), e.g.

```c
  while ((dirp = readdir(dp))) {      /* for each file */
    
    char fname[PATH_MAX];             /* storage for srchdir/d_name */
    
    /* combine srchdir PATHSEP dirp->d_name in fname */
    if (snprintf (fname, PATH_MAX, "%.*s%s%s", len, srchdir, PATHSEP, dirp->d_name)
                  >= PATH_MAX) {
      fputs ("error: combined path and filename exceeds PATH_MAX chars.\n",
              stderr);
      continue;
    }
    
    if (stat (fname, &filestat) == -1) {  /* stat fname */
      perror ("stat");
      continue;
    }
    ...
```

That way no matter what directory you provide, `stat` will have the correct path information.

An example of one approach to your code would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>    /* for opendir/closedir/readdir */
#include <dirent.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>     /* with sys/types.h for stat */
#include <unistd.h>

#include <limits.h>       /* max/min macros */

#include <inttypes.h>     /* includes stdint.h & provides PRI macros */
#include <string.h>       /* for strcpy */

#define PATHSEP "/"       /* path component separator */

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

  struct dirent *dirp;
  struct stat filestat;
  char srchdir[PATH_MAX];       /* to provide full/relative path to stat */
  char large_name[PATH_MAX]=""; /* you must provide storage for names */
  char small_name[PATH_MAX]=""; /* the pointer in stat isn't permanent */
  int64_t max = INT64_MIN;      /* .st_size is type off_t (signed int val) */
  int64_t min = INT64_MAX;
  uint64_t nfiles = 0;
  DIR *dp;

  if (argc > 1) {               /* set srchdir name (remove trailing '/') */
    size_t len;
    
    if (strlen (argv[1]) >= PATH_MAX) {  /* validate argv[1] <= PATH_MAX */
      fputs ("error: argument exceeds PATH_MAX characters.\n", stderr);
      return 1;
    }
    
    strcpy (srchdir, argv[1]);        /* copy argv[1] to srchdir */
    len = strlen (srchdir);           /* get length */
    /* if not '/' alone and if '/' found and at last char in string */
    if (len > 1 && srchdir[len-1] == '/')
      len--;                          /* len does not include the trailing '/' */
  } else {
    strcpy (srchdir, ".");            /* otherwise, use '.' */
    len = 1;
  }
  dp = opendir (srchdir);       /* opendir */
  
  if (!dp) {                    /* validate directory open */
    perror ("opendir");         /* errno set on failure, dump error */
    return 1;
  }

  while ((dirp = readdir(dp))) {      /* for each file */
    
    char fname[PATH_MAX];             /* storage for srchdir/d_name */
    
    /* combine srchdir PATHSEP dirp->d_name in fname */
    if (snprintf (fname, PATH_MAX, "%.*s%s%s", len, srchdir, PATHSEP, dirp->d_name)
                  >= PATH_MAX) {
      fputs ("error: combined path and filename exceeds PATH_MAX chars.\n",
              stderr);
      continue;
    }
    
    if (stat (fname, &filestat) == -1) {  /* stat fname */
      perror ("stat");
      continue;
    }
    

    if (S_ISREG (filestat.st_mode)) {     /* regular file */
      if (filestat.st_size > max) {       /* check/set max */
        max = (filestat.st_size);
        strcpy (large_name, fname);       /* copy large_name */
      }
      
      if (filestat.st_size < min) {       /* check/set min */
        min = (filestat.st_size);
        strcpy (small_name, fname);       /* copy small_name */
      }
      
      nfiles += 1;
    }
  }

  /* you only need 1 printf for any continual block of output
   * no matter how many lines of output that is.
   */
  if (nfiles) {
    printf ("searched %" PRIu64 " files\n"
            "the largest file is  [%" PRIu64 " bytes] %s\n"
            "the smallest file is [%" PRIu64 " bytes] %s\n", 
            nfiles, max, large_name, min, small_name);
  }
  else
    printf ("no files found in %s\n", srchdir);
  
  closedir (dp);
}
```

If compiling on Linux with gcc, you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` or pass the define in the compile string with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`.

**Example Use/Output**

Using the default directory:

```
$ ./bin/readdir_max_min
searched 3473 files
the largest file is  [176346 bytes] ./hello_world.bmp
the smallest file is [0 bytes] ./myfile.name
```

Passing a directory to your code:

```
$ ./bin/readdir_max_min ~/dev/src-cpp/tmp/debug/
searched 938 files
the largest file is  [243643 bytes] /home/david/dev/src-cpp/tmp/debug/2021-04-29-042733_838x822_scrot.png
the smallest file is [0 bytes] /home/david/dev/src-cpp/tmp/debug/outfile.txt
```

Note: since the code looks for and removes any trailing `'/'` from the end of the path the user provides, it doesn't matter if the use provides:

```
$ ./bin/readdir_max_min ~/dev/src-cpp/tmp/debug/
```

or

```
$ ./bin/readdir_max_min ~/dev/src-cpp/tmp/debug
```

And thanks to a good catch by @chqrlie, the root directory alone `'/'` is also handled correctly, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/readdir_max_min /
no files found in /
```

Also note, the reason `large_name = (dirp->d_name);` fails is the `d_name` buffer used by `readdir` isn't memory you have control over. It can be statically declared and overwritten with each new filename processed by `readdir`. That's why you must copy the actual name when each new `max` or `min` is found.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @chqrlie -- good catch. I didn't even think that far back `:)` Will update and cure the additional scenarios. The overflow of `PATH_MAX` is an intentional abuse scenario. (god knows in today's climate that is unfortunately expected). A check on the length before the copy and error handling if it doesn't fix makes sense.

Comment: Agreed -- updated to use `snprintf()` and that will prevent the buggers from trying to overflow at that point as well.

Comment: Yes, that was a bit of a bi hammer. I started with `strcspn()`, but then had to jump to `strrchr()` due to multiple possible `'/'` in the path. As you have it above is optimal with the length already obtained.

Comment: @chqrlie - thank you for your keen eye tonight. There isn't enough coffee to save me tonight. So any other tweaks I missed due to the late our, will finish up in the morning `:)` (or you are free to take the liberty and correct any other sleep deprived shortcomings I may have left lingering...)

Comment: I took the liberty to fix some remaining issues: avoiding redundant `/` and checking argument maximum length.

Comment: @chqrlie - perfect, thank you. Amazing what a good 5 hours of sleep will do `:)`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- type `int` is too small for this task: it only has 32 bits on most systems whereas files larger than 2GB are common place today. Use `long long` instead.
- `stat(dirp->d_name, &filestat)` looks for the file in the current directory. You should construct the filename from the directory name and `dirp->d_name`.
- `large_name = (dirp->d_name);` is incorrect as the value of `dirp->d_name` is only valid until the next call to `readdir()` or `closedir()`. You should copy the file name to a local array or allocate a copy with `strdup()`.
- you do not handle the case where the directory does not contain any regular files: `large_name` and `small_name` will be passed uninitialized to `printf`, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_SIZE  PATH_MAX
#else
#define PATH_SIZE  1024
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    struct stat filestat;
    const char *dirname = ".";
    long long min_size = 0, max_size = 0;
    char filename[PATH_SIZE];
    char large_name[PATH_SIZE] = "";
    char small_name[PATH_SIZE] = "";

    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Please enter ONE dir parameter\n");
        return 1;
    } else
    if (argc == 2) {
        dirname = argv[1];
    }
    dp = opendir(dirname);
    if (dp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open dir %s: %s\n", dirname, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%s/%s", dirname, dirp->d_name);
        if (!stat(filename, &filestat) && S_ISREG(filestat.st_mode)) {
            if (*large_name == '\0' || max_size < filestat.st_size) {
                max_size = filestat.st_size;
                strcpy(large_name, filename);
            }
            if (*small_name == '\0' || min_size > filestat.st_size) {
                min_size = filestat.st_size;
                strcpy(small_name, filename);
            }
        }
    }
    // Close directory and exit.
    closedir(dp);

    if (*large_name) {
        printf("the largest file is %s: %lld bytes\n", large_name, max_size);
        printf("the smallest file is %s: %lld bytes\n", small_name, min_size);
    } else {
        printf("no file in directory %s\n", dirname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `st_size` is typically a 64-bit integer, you should use:

```
int64_t min = INT64_MAX, max = INT64_MIN;
```

Also, `dirp` is dynamic (changes on every iteration of the loop), including what `dirp->dname` points to, so that your file names will always display as the last entry in the directory, regardless of its size.. Instead of copying the pointer to `small_name` and `large_name`, you should `strcpy` them:

```
char large_name[256], small_name[256];
    :
    :
strcpy(large_name,dirp->d_name);
    :
    :
strcpy(large_name,dirp->d_name);
```

Comment: `char large_name[PATH_MAX], small_name[PATH_MAX];`